# How to set width of layer-list as a whole?

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, xml-drawable

How can I specify the width of an XML drawable when using a `layer-list`? I want the width of the drawable (as a whole) to be set to 20dp but I don't where/how to set this + the preview pane doesn't help that much either.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="8dp" android:right="8dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#fff"/>
        <size android:height="10dp" android:width="20dp"/>
    </shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is not configuring size of XML drawables directly in file. You  should set the size for the view in your layout file. For example if you have some button in your code and drawable `shape.xml`, your code could look like this:

```
<Button 
 .....
  android:drawable="@drawable/shape" >
<Button>
```

But if you still wan't to set sizes you can use this code:

```
<size android:width="60dp"
    android:height="40dp" />
```